# How to adjust the axis scale in R with date?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I am trying to compare pH over time in two watersheds. For the Date, data input reads as "2020-07-17". However, I am trying to adjust the x and y axis to reflect pH data between 3 and 6, and time between 2020-07-17 and 2000-07-18. When I tried to use xlim/ ylim to adjust the scales, I received an error about the POSIXct, that no origin is found.

Currently, my code is this:

```
ggplot(W1_new, aes(x=Date, y=pH, color=Treatment) +
  geom_point(pch=19, size=1,alpha = 1) +
  theme_classic()+ theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.92,0.11))+
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Ca-treated"),
                     values = c("darkturquoise")) +
  facet_wrap(~Hor)
```

what is the correct code to get the axis to match? TIA
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjVva.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(W1_new)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(W1_new, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `limits` argument in `scale_x_datetime`

```
ggplot(W1_new, aes(x=Date, y=pH, color=Treatment) +
geom_point(pch=19, size=1,alpha = 1) +
 scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%b %d %Y",
               date_breaks = "5 year",
               limits = c(min(W1_new$Date), max(W1_new$Date))) +
theme_classic()+ theme(legend.title = element_blank())+
theme(legend.position = c(0.92,0.11))+
scale_color_manual(labels = c("Ca-treated"),
                 values = c("darkturquoise")) +
facet_wrap(~Hor)
```

I haven't run the code, but I think it should be the same. It would be helpful, but if you want exact code please provide sample data.